# Dual Monitors on Terminal Server 2003

Tags: terminal

We used to have an XPe thin client connected to a 2003 terminal server with dual monitors.

The monitors worked just like they do in windows XP.

I was wondering if anyone knew what the line was to add to the RDP file to achieve this.

So far all I have been able to find is span monitor:i:1 and that doesn't achieve the goal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what it was that you were seeing with your SPe device or if there was some server side software that helped emulate window maximizing and limiting the size of the start menu to one screen but the only way I know of to utilize two monitors when connecting to Terminal Server 2003 would be to use the /span switch to the mstsc.exe client.

The shortcut I use is the following:

```
%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe /v:d-chris /f /span
```

Comment: Thank you. Around the same time we were testing splitview. It is quite possible I imagined the switch I am thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to 
1. already be using a spanned display
2. add to the RDP file:

```
Span:i:<value>
```

*If  = 0, monitor spanning is disabled.
If  = 1, monitor spanning is enabled*

Or start the mstsc client with the /span option

Answer (score 0):

Full multi monitor support is available for XP client with the newest update to the RDP client but requires a 2008 R2 server. Sorry. If you get that, though, it is marvelous - I type that on a XP workstation at a customer site connected to my development VM having taken over both of my screens without any configuraiton (except saying "multi monitor" in the client. Works like a charm.